# How To break json string According To Page size?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I am bit rookie in jquery and trying to improve skill. 
I have got json string from ajax call. Now I only need to divide it according to grid page size;

My logic is this.

First i have taken then length of objects inside the string

```
var _totalLength = returnedData.length;
var _pageSize = 10;
var _totalPageRequired = Math.ceil(returnedData.length / _pageSize);
var array = new Array(_totalPageRequired);
```

Now I only need to create an array and place records according to page size inside it.

```
var array = new Array(_totalPageRequired);
```

Now i run the `for` loop till the `_totalPageRequired`

```
for (var i = 0; i < _totalPageRequired; i++) {
//here i am stucked, i want to know how could i assign
//per array[i] = the required data from the json string
// _totalLength = 43 and _pageSize = 10 therefore totalpagedata required is 5
// for ex:  array[0] = returnedData[from index 0 to 9]
// array[1] = returnedData[from index 10 to 19] and so on
// array[4] = returnedData[from index 40 - 43] as records end 
}
```

Anybody help me in breaking this json string.

**Edited:** My Json string is like

```
[{"UserRates":null,"RoleId":2,"Name":"M.Hassaan Khan","RoleName":null,"Password":null,"EmployeeRate":null,"Gender":null,"CategoryId":0,"CategoryName":null,"ClientId":0,"ClientName":null,"UserId":2,"Username":"hassaan09","IsMapped":false,"ProjectId":0,"ProjectName":null,"ProjectTitle":null,"CreationDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","ExpectedEndingdate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","Description":null,"ParentProjectId":0,"Cost":0.0,"Status":false},{"UserRates":null,"RoleId":2,"Name":"Bilawaal","RoleName":null,"Password":null,"EmployeeRate":null,"Gender":null,"CategoryId":0,"CategoryName":null,"ClientId":0,"ClientName":null,"UserId":5,"Username":"test_09","IsMapped":false,"ProjectId":0,"ProjectName":null,"ProjectTitle":null,"CreationDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","ExpectedEndingdate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","Description":null,"ParentProjectId":0,"Cost":0.0,"Status":false},{"UserRates":null,"RoleId":2,"Name":"Zardari","RoleName":null,"Password":null,"EmployeeRate":null,"Gender":null,"CategoryId":0,"CategoryName":null,"ClientId":0,"ClientName":null,"UserId":18,"Username":"register_09","IsMapped":false,"ProjectId":0,"ProjectName":null,"ProjectTitle":null,"CreationDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","ExpectedEndingdate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","Description":null,"ParentProjectId":0,"Cost":0.0,"Status":false},{"UserRates":null,"RoleId":2,"Name":"Nawaz","RoleName":null,"Password":null,"EmployeeRate":null,"Gender":null,"CategoryId":0,"CategoryName":null,"ClientId":0,"ClientName":null,"UserId":30,"Username":"testing111","IsMapped":false,"ProjectId":0,"ProjectName":null,"ProjectTitle":null,"CreationDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","ExpectedEndingdate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","Description":null,"ParentProjectId":0,"Cost":0.0,"Status":false}]
```

And after ajax success i am doing `Json.Parse(data.d)` so it convert it into objects;

Comment: how's your json format? can you show us an example about how your data should be stored into array? any jsfiddle?

Comment: @Andres i have edited please check

Comment: what do you mean when you say _pageSize = 10? do you want to print 10 elements by page?

Comment: no of records to be shown inside grid page = 10 ie per page 10 records

Comment: do you want something like this http://jsfiddle.net/aras7/b83uzccn/1/ ?

Comment: welcome, I'll move it to answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/aras7/b83uzccn/1/

```
var _totalLength = returnedData.length;
var _pageSize = 2;

var array = [];

var page = 0;
for(var i = 0;i < returnedData.length;){
    var page_data = []; 
    for(var j = 0;j < _pageSize && i < returnedData.length;j++) {
        page_data.push(returnedData[i]);
        i++;
    }
    array.push(page_data)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Typing this on my phone so it lacks explanation, hope it helps and is what you're looking for.

```
var _totalLength = returnedData.length;
var _pageSize = 10;
var array = [];
var i = -1;
var currenPage:
while(++i< _totalLength){
  currentPage = Math.floor(i/_pageSize);
  array [currentPage] =   array [currentPage] || [];
  array [currentPage].push(returnedData[i]);
}
```